# How to dry-run sql update query using spring jpa and postgresql

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to know what happens when i would run update on db without change actually executing query on table.
I am using spring boot, jpa and db is postgresql.
Any ideas?

I don't have idea how can i do that